# Simple login with Angular not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying out Angular and really loving it. I need to make a login page for my app that I am building, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the `$location` feature works.

**Problem**

I'm using routes, which was pretty easy to put together, and for each link I use a hashtag setup, ex. `<a href='#home'>Home</a>` then that will just take me to the home.html view based on what controller in assign in the routes. However, when I try and set the action in a form ex `<form action='#home'>...` it fails, so now I'm confused.

Here is what I mean by fails. With my current set up I can click submit on the login view (just to test the functionality, I'm not using a username or password) and it will transition to the `home.html` view, but it will not display any data from the home controller. It doesn't even recognize the `ng-view` directive on the primary template.

In this problem, I'd like be able to deliver the best possible structure.

**Primary Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='css/combined.css' />
    <script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/angular-fake-browser.js'></script>
    <script src='js/crewpoint.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='crewpoint'>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default nevbar-fixed-top'>
        <div class='navbar-brand navbar-brand-center'>CrewPoint</div>
    </nav>

    <section class='page {{ pageClass }}' ng-view>
        
    </section>

    <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom'></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views**

login.html

```
<div class='row'>
    <section class='col-xs-12'>
        <form id='login' ng-submit='login()'>
            <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='username' placeholder='username'/>
            </article>
            <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                <input type="password" class='form-control' id='password' placeholder='password'/>
            </article>
            <article class='form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-block btn-primary'>Login</button>
            </article>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

home.html

```
<main class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>
            <h2>Projects</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 no-padding'>
            <ul class='list-group'>
                <li class='list-group-item' ng-repeat="project in projectList track by $index">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'>
                            <p><strong>{{project.customer}}</strong></p>
                            <p><em>{{project.product}}</em></p>
                            <address>
                                {{project.address.line1}}<br>
                                {{project.address.city}}, {{project.address.state}} {{project.address.zip}}
                            </address>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'>
                            <p>$ {{project.amount}}</p>
                            <p><a href='#projects'>View Project</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**Controllers**

```
var crewpoint = angular.module('crewpoint', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

crewpoint.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        tempalteUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'Home'
    });
});

crewpoint.controller('Login', function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'login';
    $scope.login = function(){
        $location.url('/home');
    };
});

crewpoint.controller('Home', function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'home-page';
    $scope.projectList = [
        {
            customer : 'Bob Marley',
            address : {
                line1 : '123 Main St',
                city : 'Omaha',
                state : 'NE',
                zip : '68137'
            },
            product : 'SmartJack',
            amount : '12,345.67'
        },
        {
            customer : 'Jimmy Matteo',
            address : {
                line1 : '456 Main St',
                city : 'La Vista',
                state : 'NE',
                zip : '68137'
            },
            product : 'PowerBrace',
            amount : '45,678.90'
        }
    ];
});
```

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) about form submittin using `angularjs`

Comment: I was actually just reading about the ng-submit, but that still doesn't answer the second part of my question as to by the ng-view for `home.html` is not firing correctly.

Comment: Oh, so read about [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) then

Comment: Again, this would apply to me if I wasn't using routes. I'm using routes, this doesn't apply to me in this sense.

Comment: Doesn't your $location.url('/home'); (from your  ng-click='login') refresh the page and make it loose the data?

Comment: that shouldn't matter

Comment: You also have the form action that send to #home + the ng-click='login()'. Perhaps choose one way or the other for better structure.

Comment: I have updated the form to represent the current state